# How to make SharePoint 2010 Page compatible in IE 6.0?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, sharepoint-2010

How to make SharePoint 2010 Page compatible in IE 6.0?

Has anyone worked on similar requirement???

Basically what all things to take care?

e.g. Ribbon control

If any one has any reference links/documents, please suggest.

Regards,

Ketan

Answer (score 1):

You will find this requirement difficult to satisfy as not even Microsoft are supporting IE6 in the 2010 release of SharePoint.  So, you're pretty much on your own as any out of the box stuff may not work IE6.  I would push back against such an unreasonable requirement, otherwise you may have to switch platforms (or roll back to 2007).